# win32clipboard.SetClipboardText() doesn't work

Tags: python, clipboard, pywin32

I have a Python script that reads the clipboard, processes the contents, and updates the clipboard with new information. Here's my code:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
toSearch = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
# Do stuff
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(result)
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Reading the text afterward with `GetClipboardData()` returns the text I set to it, but a normal right-click+paste or control-v returns what was previously there. Is this a bug in pywin32 or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe you need to call `EmptyClipboard` first. Why aren't you checking any of the return values?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep, that worked. What return values should I be checking for?

Comment: I don't know exactly. It's just that step one of diagnosing a problem is checking the error codes, if there are any - and in this case there are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will works:

```
result = 'Some Text'
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText( result, win32clipboard.CF_TEXT )
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: Vauge answer, but the EmptyClipboard call seem to do the trick nonetheless!